# angular chunk repeat itself

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have function where I push items to array by scrolling the page but the problem is that pushed items are repeating instead of pushing new items.

#### Code

```
onScroll(): void {
      console.log('scrolled');
      var i,j,newArray,chunk = 10;
      for (i=0,j=this.listOfData.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
          newArray = this.listOfData.slice(i,i+chunk);
          this.results = this.results.concat(newArray);
      }
}
```

My `this.listOfData` array has 19 items and it only gets 19 to 10 (repeating) 9 to 1 never shows.

[Source of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/8490993)

**Any idea?**

## Update

In case you have hard time understand my point i recorder small video of my issue [Watch](https://streamable.com/uym05f)

Comment: Hard to understand the exact scenario. Could you add a stackblitz please?

Comment: @JinsThomasShaji that would be hard regarding to my data api, but i make video shot for you.

Comment: @JinsThomasShaji updated

Comment: Saw the video. Many reasons for this behaviour. Better if you can provide more context. You can simply reproduce in stackbltz using some mock-up or hard-coded data instead of using API. Then it'll be easy to find the exact cause and solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing because of the issue mentioned by Aditya in the answer above. Change your code like this :

```
       onScroll(): void {
          console.log('scrolled');
          var index,newArray,chunk = 10;
          if(this.result.length == 0){
              newArray = this.listOfData.slice(0,chunk);
              this.results = this.results.concat(newArray);
          }
          else if(this.results.length < this.listOfData.length){
             index=this.result.length-1;
             newArray = this.listOfData.slice(index,index+chunk);
             this.results = this.results.concat(newArray);
          }
       }
```

Comment: WOW! love it :D may i ask what this mean? `this.results.length-1` why `-1`?

Comment: This identifies the number of elements already present in the this.result array.

Comment: so that `-1` is equal to `10` in first load and it's equal to `20` after first scroll?

Comment: It's because the indexing of the array starts from 0. Your 11th element in the array will be found at arr[10].

Answer (score 0):

Since every time your function executes your `i` value will be set to 0 and `chunk` is 10, it will always slice out the same chunk from your array. This is why you have repeating data.

[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does not modify the original array, if that is where the confusion is arising.

In such a case alter your code to:

```
onScroll(): void {
      console.log('scrolled');
      var i,j,newArray,chunk = 10;
      for (i=0,j=this.listOfData.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
          newArray = this.listOfData.splice(i,i+chunk);
          this.results = this.results.concat(newArray);
      }
}
```

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will delete the chunk from the original array and return the deleted chunk.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I recommended splice since it seemed like that was what you were trying to do. If you can explain your problem better, I may be able to give a better solution

Comment: Ok, `issue` remember that I said my `19 to 10 (repeating)`? now they are not repeating nor `9 to 1` is printing! it just stops on first load. `what I want` at first load show `19 to 10` and when I scroll down add `9 to 1` into `19 to 10` so I will have full list `19 to 1`

Comment: What if your data had (let's say) 35 items. Do you want to show all 35 items on scrolling down once or just the next 10 ? @mafortis

Comment: then it should show like: `10-10-10-5` it just adds up